# What is the differnce between a blue shift and a red shift?

Tags: doppler-effect

The blue and the red shift, how do they explain expansion of universe?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows [insufficient prior research](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5778/what-counts-as-sufficient-prior-research-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We observe that the light that is coming from most of the galaxies is redshifted. When a source of light is moving away from you, the wavelength of the light that is emitted by that object gets redshifted (you measure the wavelength as being longer). Blueshift, on the other hand, happens when the source of light is coming towards you.

So if we measure that the light coming from most of the galaxies is redshifted, that means that they are getting away from us. Note that there is a correlation between velocity and distance. The amount of redshift is proportional to the distance to that galaxy. The more distant a galaxy is, the faster it is receding from us. This is the evidence for the expansion of the Universe. This observations indicate that is the space between the galaxies that is expanding.